# I need help making a raspberry pi zero w Cluster

Tags: pi-4, cluster, rpio

I want to make a raspberry pi zero w Cluster but I want to make the main computer my raspberry pi4. But I can’t find any Tutorials that have this case. I already have 11 pi zeros an internet switch ((catalyst 3750G)it has its spf module slots as fiber in and the other 10/100/1000 ports as Ethernet), Ethernet cables and a raspberry pi 4.
If someone could give a list of products along with instructions on how to set up the hardware and software that would be much appreciated. I also have a budget of $200 USD.